# Auto-forward RestController request header(s) to all RestTemplate requests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul

Consider users sending requests to service A, which then implements business logic that includes submitting multiple requests to services B, C etc.

Service A is implemented using a `RestController`, which receives certain headers (e.g. `Authorization`) from users.

Service A then submits requests to services B, C etc. using a `RestTemplate` bean.

**How does one make it automatically forward service A `RestController` headers with any requests submitted via the `RestTemplate` bean to services B, C etc.?**

The goal here is to avoid specifying these headers explicitly on every `RestTemplate` request. The ultimate goals are:

1. Enable a zero-trust microservice architecture, where all requests between internal services are authenticated.
2. Preserve authenticated user context for all requests from (1).
3. Do it with the least amount of change possible.

I've heard recommendations using Zuul or similar proxies for such things, but wanted to confirm if this is the best/most common/suitable approach for this particular scenario. What makes me pause on it is that service A is *not* a simple "proxy" service that just forwards requests on different routes, but rather a rich REST API that needs to "use" other services, rather than simply forward/enrich incoming requests. So I'm not sure if Zuul or other proxies would be fully suitable for it.

To make it a bit more concrete, I'd like to avoid having to modify logic like this:

```
    @GetMapping("/baz")
    public Baz getBaz() {
        final Foo foo = restTemplate.getForObject("http://service-b/foo", Foo.class)
        final Bar bar = restTemplate.getForObject("http://service-c/bar/{barId}", Bar.class, foo.getBarId());
        return bar.getBaz();
    }
```

While one could replace `restTemplate.getForObject(...)` with: `restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(req.getHeaders()), Response.class, param)`, doing so is undesirable for services with *many* API calls.

Alternatively, doing so via a `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` would only be possible if were able to access `GetMapping`'s per-request header inside the interceptor.

Any concrete examples would be much appreciated!

**Update:** I may have found answers to similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55321762/2962507) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61720539/2962507). Looks like the missing pieces have been `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()` for MVC and `subscriberContext` for WebFlux.